# Limit returned MySQL results from PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fix an issue with our website and I'm afraid it is a bit out of my depth at the moment.  We have a social network website and users can search for friends through a friend section.

The problem is that when you open that section the SELECT query seems to run a search for ALL users on the site.  And we have over 15,000 users so the page is incredibly slow and normally times out.

I was able to limit the displayed result to 15 users per page, but the query is not well optimized and apparently selecting all users.

Here is the SELECT query code we have at the moment:

```
$sql_sel_friend_req = "SELECT m.*, mp.iMAgeGroup as modelAgeGroup, 
c.iMAgeGroup as clientAgeGroup, mo.iModelId, mp.vImage as modelImage, 
cc.vImage as clientImage FROM member m
left join model as mo on (mo.iModelId = m.MemberId && m.MemberType = 'Model') 
left join model_profile as mp on (mp.iModelId = mo.iModelId) 
left join client as c on (c.iClientId = m.MemberId && m.MemberType = 'Client') 
left join client_company as cc on (cc.iClientId = c.iClientId) WHERE m.MemberId != " . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Id'] . " && m.MemberStatus = 'Active' &&
m.MemberId not in (SELECT distinct(mf.iFriendMemberId1) from member_friends mf where mf.iFriendMemberId2 = " . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Id'] . " && mf.eFriendMemberType2 = '" . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Type'] . "') &&
m.MemberId not in (SELECT distinct(mf1.iFriendMemberId2) from member_friends mf1 where mf1.iFriendMemberId1 = " . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Id'] . " && mf1.eFriendMemberType1 = '" . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Type'] . "') ";
```

I've tried to use Limit and Offset but this only caused SQL errors.

If you have any ideas please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you post the error code in your question as well?

Comment: add the error that you are encountering while using `limit`

Comment: I tried to add the LIMIT again but now I get a blank page.

Comment: m.MemberId not in (SELECT distinct(mf1.iFriendMemberId2) from member_friends mf1 where mf1.iFriendMemberId1 = " . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Id'] . " && mf1.eFriendMemberType1 = '" . $_SESSION['sess_Login_Type'] . "') LIMIT 5;

Comment: I added the above to the last section.  Disclaimer I am not a PHP expert as you can probably tell.

Comment: you might want to try executing your query in phpmyadmin to know the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please provide the offending SQL as well as the exact error message that you are receiving. Also, you may want to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve